# PHP getting information about an object

Tags: php

If I have an object, how can I know the details of the object. Like the file in which it is defined, its methods, properties etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

If you want something simpler, there's `get_class_methods()`, `get_object_methods()`, `get_class_vars()`, `get_object_vars()`, etc.

Comment: thanks.. i was looking for get_object_methods and get_object_vars.. I couldn't use Reflection classes, since I want the info based on the object i have in hand..

Comment: No `get_object_methods()` though.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [PHP reflection functionalities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
echo $class->getFileName()."\n";
var_dump($class->getMethods());
var_dump($class->getProperties());
```

**Edit:**

`ReflectionClass` is used on classes and `ReflectionObject` on objects.